# Insert date on Netbeans comment?

Tags: java, netbeans

How do I insert the date to Netbeans comment?

I can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> for date and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>"</kbd> for time in Libre Office and Kjots.

I found this plugin but the links seems to be dead.

https://sharesource.org/svn/defcon3/date_time/org-defcon-date_time_nb.nbm

https://fredreh.wordpress.com/2008/06/12/insert-date-time-in-netbeans-module/